# ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded - Python 2.7 Script

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

I'm running a script based off the HP Warranty API (this is the sample code they provide) and I'm getting a "ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded" error. I'm not sure how to proceed.

I've triple checked my API key/secret. I'm using python 2.7.12 at the moment.

I cut off the end of the code to save space, but this is where I'm getting stuck.

```
import requests
import json
import time
import dateutil.parser
import datetime

apiKey='mykey'
apiSecret='mysecret'
tokenBody = { 'apiKey': apiKey, 'apiSecret': apiSecret, 'grantType': 'client_credentials', 'scope': 'warranty' }

data = [
    #{ 'sn': '5CG7194P32', 'pn': 'V7B61UC' },
    { 'sn': '5CG7194P32', 'pn': 'V7B61UC' }
]
def _url(path):
    return 'https://css.api.hp.com' + path

# Get the access token
tokenHeaders = { 'Accept': 'application/json' }
tokenResponse = requests.post(_url('/oauth/v1/token'), data=tokenBody, headers=tokenHeaders)
tokenJson = tokenResponse.json() #GETTING STUCK HERE
token = tokenJson['access_token']

# Create the batch job
jobHeaders = {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token,
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}
print('Creating new batch job...')
jobResponse = requests.post(_url('/productWarranty/v2/jobs/'), data=json.dumps(data), headers=jobHeaders)
job = jobResponse.json()
print('Batch job created successfully.')
print('--------------------')
print('Job ID: ' + job['jobId'])
print('Estimated time in seconds to completion: ' + str(job['estimatedTime']))
print('')
```

Here is the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hp_test2.py", line 22, in <module>
    tokenJson = tokenResponse.json()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/models.py", line 800, in json
    self.content.decode(encoding), **kwargs
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 339, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 364, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 382, in raw_decode
    raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

Adding answers to comments below:

```
Content: scope=warranty&apiKey=mykey&apiSecret=mysecret&grantType=client_credentials
Status Code: 200
```

Comment: Have you printed `tokenResponse.content` to see what it looks like?

Comment: Also look at `tokenResponse.status_code`.  If it's not 200, you might have an error.

Comment: ```Content: scope=warranty&apiKey=mykey&apiSecret=mysecret&grantType=client_credentials
Status Code: 200```

Answer (score 0):

It could be that this API changed and it's not returning JSON anymore (?). Try reading further into the documentation to check if there is an additional way of requesting JSON data as `Accept: application/json` seems to be ignored by the server.

For now, you could spice it up a little bit, assuming your response will always be either JSON or query params:

```
import urlparse

...

try:
    job = jobResponse.json()
except ValueError:
    job = urlparse.parse_qs(jobResponse.content)
```

Either way you'll get a dictionary out of the response. Take into account that `parse_qs` returns a dictionary were it's values are `list()` to comply with RFC specifications:

```
{'scope': ['warranty'], 'apiKey': ['mykey'], 'apiSecret': ['mysecret'], 'grantType': ['client_credentials']}
```